# Search data in a large Mysql table

Tags: mysql, performance

My question is a bit wired one.

I do have a big data table (more than 1 million rows). All the records in the top are history records, which are rearly use. All the new and frequently using data is at the bottom. So I feel that if my table is searched from bottom to top, the performance will be good. So is there any way to achive this other than using indexes? Or is it just a useless thought?

Comment: `1 million rows` is not a big table, in fact I would say it is pretty small. Run `show create table table_name`   and post it on the question. If you have performance issue you should run `explain your query` and post that too

Comment: "other than using indexes" -- Use INDEXes!  Show us the query and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; we can help you write a good index.

Comment: @ErgestBasha Honestly I'm pretty much satisfied with my query speed. I just wanted to know whether it can be improved by using a search from bottom.

Comment: 'search from bottom' - data is not stored in any specific order so the notion of top and bottom is simply wrong. Appropriate indexes are the way to improve performance , although in some cases the optimiser may choose not to use them. there is a whole section in the manual devoted to optimisation which includes https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimization-indexes.html

Answer (score 0):

Certain queries will be faster if you search `ORDER BY foo DESC` instead of `ORDER BY foo ASC`.  But in most such cases, adding a suitable `INDEX` will provide much more speedup.

Without an `ORDER BY`, the Optimizer will do whatever it thinks might be fastest.  This might involve scanning the table in the order it is stored on the disk -- which will be ascending through the `PRIMARY KEY`.  You *do have* a PK, don't you?  Maybe that is what you mean by "bottom" and "top"?  But there is only one direction that is likely to happen.

My blog on indexing:  [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)